# Magento 2 Search doesn't work properly

Tags: magento2, catalog, search

Following is the title of my product in Magento store.

I want to use the same exact phrase for

**Nose Wash Sign 7 x 10 In GRN and BK/WHT, 9NYA5**

the above string has (11 words 45 characters)
So is it possible to get the exact product currently it's showing Your search returned no results?

Is there a configuration search with the exact phrase or any other extension that will solve the issue?